# cannot fix: Could not find kotlin-reflect-1.3.72.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.3.72)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

i pulled code that my frined wrote and now i got this error:

```
Could not find kotlin-reflect-1.3.72.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.3.72).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.3.72/kotlin-reflect-1.3.72.jar
```

how ever my fried didn't used any kotlin code or plugin.

i try to:

download the library he telling me to and adding it.

adding the dependencies:

  implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

  classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

  compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"

add maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

clean project

restart Android studio and my PC

delete gradle cash (it failed to do so)

my friend dont get this error but i do and when i go back in the versions the error disappear but then we lose our code.
i feel like im out of options

this is my gradle(app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.rems"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.mini_window_style.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            resources {
                srcDirs 'src/main/resources'
            }
            java {
                srcDirs 'src/main/java', 'src/main/java/module'
            }
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation files('libs\\natty-0.13.jar')
    implementation files('libs/antlr-4.9-complete.jar')
    implementation files('libs\\antlr-4.9-complete.jar')
    implementation files('libs\\slf4j-android-1.7.30.jar')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation "com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0"
    implementation files('libs\\natty-0.13.jar')
    implementation files('libs\\antlr-4.9-complete.jar')

}
```

and that's my gradle(android project):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'

        

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```